# How can I answer phone calls with a real (like power) button?

Tags: calls, xiaomi, android-10, buttons, android-one

I can close phone calls with that button by default, but for me it would be even more useful to be able to answer a phone call the same way.

Is there a setting or an application that would enable that?

The main idea is to be able to answer a call without interacting with the touch-screen, but only with the real buttons.

This is a Xiaomi a2 phone, not rooted.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). So I've rephrased your question to fit here. // Note that at least some custom ROMs have such a setting IIRC.

Comment: Another detail we might need: is the device rooted? Are e.g. modules for Xposed or Magisk an option?

Comment: What phone is it? I know samsung has an option to answer calls using the volume button

Comment: @aBochur- Xiaomi non-rooted phone, added that info.

Comment: @Izzy -  `Xposed or Magisk` - no idea what those are. Phone is a non-rooted Xiaomi a2.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That limits possible solutions. A vague idea that *might* work (not tried): [tag:automation] solutions like [tag:tasker], a la: "conditions: phone rings & button X pressed; action: accept call".